# How to implement Multilevel inheritance in code first

Tags: c#, sql, code-first

I am using Code First approach for creating Database. I am trying to use TPH(table per hierarchy) inheritance. My POCO classes are :

```
public abstract class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    ...
}

public abstract class PersonalDetail : Address
{
    public int PersonalDetailId { get; set; }
    ...   
}

public partial class AccountHolder : PersonalDetail
{
    public int AccountHolderId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Nominee : PersonalDetail
{
    public int NomineeId { get; set; }
}
```

I have created 2 abstract classes *Address* and *PersonalDetail* and 2 derived classes *AccountHolder* and *Nominee*. *PersonalDetail* inherits *address* and further *AccountHolder* and *Nominee* inherits *PersonalDetail*. My fluent api code is :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().Map<PersonalDetail>(m => m.Requires("AddressOf"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonalDetail>().Map<AccountHolder>(m => m.Requires("PersonalDetailOf"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonalDetail>().Map<Nominee>(m => m.Requires("PersonalDetailOf"));
```

Now when i tried to insert data it throws an exception, i.e. :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Addresses_dbo.Addresses_AccountHolder_AddressId' on table 'Addresses' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Can anybody please tell me whats the problem and how can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should WillCascadeOnDelete false

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.)
                    .WithMany(t => t.)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Or use this code\

```
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Comment: I used             `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();` but still the same error, can you please elaborate your solution, i am totally new in Code first world, thanks!